# Pass Button object to method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4

I am trying to write a generic method that would allow me to pass the following: "x", "y" "object" and then have it move.  Currently I have this:

```
 -(void) changeObjectLocations: (integer_t) xSpot: (integer_t) ySpot: (id) sender   {

  if (![sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
   {
       UIButton *myObject = (UIButton *)sender;
       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5              
        animations:^{                
        CGRect newFrame = myObject.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x = xSpot;
        newFrame.origin.y = ySpot;
        myObject.frame = newFrame;
    }];             
}
  else if (![sender isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
  {
    UILabel *myObject = (UILabel *)sender;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5  animations:^{                
        CGRect newFrame = myObject.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x = xSpot;
        newFrame.origin.y = ySpot;
        myObject.frame = newFrame;
    }];  
  }
}
```

I then want to call it like so:

```
-(void) orientationBlockLandscape {

    [self changeObjectLocations: 456 :282 : btn1] ;
    [self changeObjectLocations: 391 :227 : lblTitle] ;

}
```

Although it is working, on compile I get the following warning:

SecondViewController.m:33: warning: 'SecondViewController' may not respond to '-changeObjectLocations:::'

Is there a better way I can/should be passing the object?  Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Geo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the warning outputted, it sounds like you didn't define `changeObjectLocations` in the header of your SecondViewController -- or it's not the same signature as what you've implemented.

Comment: That was it.  New to Objective-C so I always forget something!  Thanks

Comment: @No problem.  Great name by the way! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler looks for selectors which are the method definitions with the variables and return removed.

So a method like:

```
-(void) setObject:(id) anObject forKey:(NSString *) keyname;
```

... would have a selector of:

```
setObject:forKey:
```

Therefore, your method of:

```
 -(void) changeObjectLocations: (integer_t) xSpot: (integer_t) ySpot: (id) sender
```

... will have a selector of:

```
changeObjectLocations:xSpot:ySpot:
```

Note that the parameter names are part of the selector so:

```
changeObjectLocations:xSpot:ySpot:
```

and

```
changeObjectLocations:::
```

.. are two entirely separate selectors which represent two entirely separate methods.

Although it is legal in the language to use parameters without names e.g. ":::" it is very, very poor practice largely because it is to easy to get a naming collision. Being explicit not only makes the code easier to read and maintain but makes it easier for the complier and runtime to function.